# What is the difference between 'ColorModeProvider' and 'ColorModeScript' in Chakra-UI?

Tags: chakra-ui

In the chakra-ui readme, it is [mentioned](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui) to use `ColorModeProvider` for dark & light theme mode. But in chakra-ui website, it is [mentioned](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/color-mode) to use `ColorModeScript` for the same.

I am confused between these. What is the difference b/w `ColorModeProvider` and `ColorModeScript`?

Searched for the difference in Google but didn't find any clarification.

Answer (score 3):

I was wondering the same thing and did some research/testing today. Here's what I found with references linked in the footnotes. I hope it's helpful, or at least a starting point, in explaining the difference between `ColorModeProvider` and `ColorModeScript`.

---

`ColorModeProvider` provides functionality for toggling and rendering components by color mode, like toggling component CSS classes from light to dark. Changing `toggleColorMode` for content not wrapped in/using the `ColorModeProvider` would not change the content's color mode.

Luckily, `ColorModeProvider` is built into `ChakraProvider` and `ChakraBaseProvider`<sup>1, 2</sup> with newer versions, and does not need to be added separately. <sup>3</sup>

chakra-provider return includes `ColorModeProvider`<sup>2</sup>:

```
return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme as Dict} cssVarsRoot={cssVarsRoot}>
      <ColorModeProvider
        colorModeManager={colorModeManager}
        options={theme.config}
      >
        {/* Children/additional settings omitted to save lines */}
      </ColorModeProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
```

---

`ColorModeScript` generates and inserts a script as the first item in the root element that helps read the user's system preference for color mode, as well as set and get the user's color preference setting from local storage. It also appears to add/remove the appropriate `body` CSS class for Chakra's light/dark mode.<sup>4</sup> The `ColorModeScript` configuration is placed as close as possible to the start of the  tag.

The [documentation for ColorModeScript](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/color-mode#adding-the-colormodescript) is quite short, so I looked at the source code<sup>5</sup> and sandbox tested<sup>6</sup> to understand its impact. The documentation mentions that preference storage can also be handled server-side, and if implemented server-side, the `ColorModeScript` does not need to be used.<sup>7</sup>

Generated script example from `ColorModeScript` Chakra inserts into the root element:

```
<div id="root">
    <script id="chakra-script">
        !(function(){try{var a=function(c){var v="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)",h=window.matchMedia(v).matches?"dark":"light",r=c==="system"?h:c,o=document.documentElement,s=document.body,l="chakra-ui-light",d="chakra-ui-dark",i=r==="dark";return s.classList.add(i?d:l),s.classList.remove(i?l:d),o.style.colorScheme=r,o.dataset.theme=r,r},n=a,m="system",e="chakra-ui-color-mode",t=localStorage.getItem(e);t?a(t):localStorage.setItem(e,a(m))}catch(a){}})();
    </script>
</div>
```

---

<sup>**Reference**</sup>
<sub><sup>1</sup> [chakra-ui GitHub](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/components/provider/src/chakra-provider.tsx): Source code for `ChakraProvider`</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> See link 1 line 100. Shows `ChakraProvider`/`ChakraBaseProvider` source code where it returns `ThemeProvider` and `ColorModeProvider` wrapping children</sub>
<sub><sup>3</sup> [chakra-ui GitHub](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/.changelog/v1.6.0.mdx#L52): Patch notes v1.6.0 shows it's recommended to use `ChakraProvider` over `ThemeProvider`/`ColorModeProvider` pattern</sub>
<sub><sup>4</sup> [chakra-ui GitHub](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/components/color-mode/src/color-mode-script.tsx): Shows the script set in the root element (example also above) that manages local storage preference, body class names, etc. See line 34 re: localStorage.</sub>
<sub><sup>5</sup> See link 4 for `ColorModeScript` source code</sub>
<sub><sup>6</sup> [Replit Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/chakra-ui-color-mode-test-f5fcwr?file=/src/uiLayer.chakra/customTheme.ts): Credit to user tresorama for the helpful sandbox</sub>
<sub><sup>7</sup> [chakra-ui GitHub](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/components/color-mode/CHANGELOG.md): v2.0.1 patch notes indicate addition of server-side setting with configuration examples, around line 213 at time of writing.</sub>